# Sql query where x is a value between two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a table with the following columns

```
comment
minAge
maxAge
```

and the following rows:

```
comment, minAge, maxAge
"Baby", 1, 5
"Teen", 13, 19
"Adult", 20, 50
```

Is it possible to do a sql query like:

```
select * from rows where 16 between minAge and maxAge
```

With the results:

```
"Teen", 13, 19
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I have not created the table yet. I am not sure if such a query is even possible, which is why I asked. I don't know if the way I am approaching the problem is the right way, and knowing the answer would help me along.

Comment: It's perfectly fine (and easy to test)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[BETWEEN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) operator selects values within a range. The values can be numbers, text, or dates.

See your table and data yourself [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c8355/1)